# Data entry twice in database when click button submit

Tags: php, html

Why when I click on the submit button for the first data it just entered in the database but it is not in the page view. after that click again once the data is entered in the page, but when I check the database, the data is two of the same. how about.

```html
<?php
include 'xx.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post" >

       <center>
                    <div>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label><b>User</b></label>
                                <input type="user" placeholder="User" name="user" required>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label><b>Position</b></label>
                                <input type="position" placeholder="Position" name="position" required>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label><b>Serial Number</b></label>
                                <input type="serial" placeholder="Serial Number" name="serialnumber" required>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <td>
                            <center>


                                  <input type="submit" name="send"  value="Submit"></input></center>

                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
       
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $position=$_POST['position'];
        $serialnumber=$_POST['serialnumber'];
        
        
        $xx="INSERT INTO xx (user,position,serialnumber)VALUES('$user','$position','$serialnumber')";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql);
 echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location.href='xx.php'</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: There's too little code to effectively answer your question.

Comment: What KIKO Software said plus put the php at the top of the file and see if that changes the way the page works.

Comment: What is `xx.php`? Does it output a stand-alone HTML document? Suppose it must, since you are redirecting there. But then you are also embedding the same(?) script on top of your other script, so if that was the case, you would have html, head, body etc. twice in the output ... _“it just entered in the database but it is not in the page view”_ - and where does that happen, where is the data read back from the database and displayed on the page? // Please go read [ask].

Comment: I know English can be difficult, but spending a more time writing/translating the question would help people a lot :)

Comment: @martindilling thankyou :))

Answer (score 1):

Try this. When you click the button it will disable the button, change the text and then submit the form.

That means the button will be disabled for anymore clicks.

```
<input 
    type="submit" 
    name="send" 
    value="Submit" 
    onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Submitting...';this.form.submit();"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible to add this code on top section and review my code.

```
  $i=1;
    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $position=$_POST['position'];
        $serialnumber=$_POST['serialnumber'];
        $department=$_POST['department'];
        if($i==1):
            $sql="INSERT INTO xx (user,position,serialnumber,department)VALUES('$user','$position','$serialnumber','$department')";
            $result=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql);
            $i++;
        endif;

        if(isset($result) && !empty($result)):
            $i=1;
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location.href='xx.php'</script>";

        endif;
    }
```

Comment: data does not go into page view and does not go to page view.

Comment: Please check all conditions using echo based value. Where goes incorrect please check.